# VBA How to display array in message box

Tags: arrays

VBA

Hi I have been trying create an array then display in a msgbox but keep getting this error:

'Invalid procedure call or argument'

I have used the Join function on another array and it works

```
Sub rangearray()

Dim array1 As Variant

array1 = Range("a1:z1")

MsgBox Join(array1, vbCrLf)

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Also, please tag the question so we can understand which language you're talking about.

Comment: I wrote VBA in the title, don't where its gone

Answer (score 14):

I've just tested it on a simple way on VB6 and it worked with this:

```
Dim arr(3) As String

arr(1) = "Test"
arr(2) = "Test 2"
arr(3) = "Test 3"

MsgBox Join(arr, vbCrLf)
```

are you certain that your function 'Range("a1:z1")' it's actually returning an array object to the variant 'array1'?

**EDIT:**
you can't pass a multi-dimensional array on Join function, it has to be an One-dimensional to work properly. So, if the expression array1(1,1) returns an value, that's your problem.

Comment: I tried your script and it worked, I don't what the issue is with using range?

Comment: i don't know either what that function is returning, but the point is, put a break point on the MsgBox line. Then, check the value of 'array1', it should be an array, because the "Join" function is expecting an array.

Comment: you can't pass a multi-dimensional array on Join function, it has to be an One-dimensional to work properly. So, if the expression `array1(1,1)` returns an value, that's your problem.